# Speed problems with 3 like statements in 1 query (oracle)

Tags: php, sql, oracle, performance, sql-like

This is a snippet of my query:

```
and (
    ADDR_FULLTEXT
    like upper(:streets1)
)
```

Whenever i execute the query this is a part of, it executes in about 0.05 seconds. This is perfect!
But, when I do the following:

```
and (
    ADDR_FULLTEXT
    like upper(:streets1)
    AND
    ADDR_FULLTEXT
    like upper(:streets2)
)
```

it results in a 20 second query. Why is the difference this big, and how can solve this?

What the rest of the query basically does, is selecting multiple fields from a view (ADDR_FULLTEXT is one of them). 
There also is another like, just like this one.

Maybe i'm doing something really wrong here, and maybe therefor there is a better way of doing this.

FYI: A PHP loop generates this query, which results from an explode of a search query. Every word is parsed in this query resulting in 1 or more of the same "like" in 1 query. Another like is generated the same way, but this is always 1 like, never more, never less.

Comment: Can you post the query plan for the two versions of the SQL statement?

Comment: ADDR_FULLTEXT is not indexed. It's made out of 6 different text fields combined, which are indexed. This all happens in a View. Unfortunately i have to stick with that.

Comment: There indeed is a full table scan which can't be avoided because of inconsistent data in the database. therefor i need to use a replace. Query is not the problem, the database data (which is not in my control) is. Thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try breaking it down into two different queries, and taking the intersection, like:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ADDR_FULLTEXT like upper(:streets1)
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ADDR_FULLTEXT like upper(:streets2)
```

see [Intersect](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Intersect)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will have a full table scan for each LIKE statement, and the rest of your query uses indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The change to this predicate is probably changing the CBO's estimate of the number of rows that will be returned by the table. This in turn may cause a significant restructuring of the plan, resulting in a change in performance.

Further analysis will have to wait until you provide the query (including views) and query plans.